# With ElasticSearch sort by given array

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I'm storing in ElasticRearch a series of feeds. Each feed is has the actor posting such feed and the posting date. In another place I store a weighted value for each actor in this way:

```
weights: [{'id': 'mark', 'weight': 1}, {'id': 'jane', 'weight': 3}]
```

I need to query the feeds grouped by date but ordered by such weights. I tried to make a sorting function using painless but I'm stuck in defining the weights:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "actor.id": "mark"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "range": {
                                    "published": {"gte": "2017-09-30T15:37:21.530483"}
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "actor.id": "jane"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "range": {
                                    "published": {"gte": "2017-09-30T15:37:21.530483"}
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "dates": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "published_date",
            },
            "aggs": {
                "top_verbs_hits": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "sort": {
                            "_script": {
                                "type": "number",
                                "script": {
                                    "lang": "painless",
                                    "source": "def weights = [{'id': 'mark', 'weight': 1}, {'id': 'jane', 'weight': 3}]; def weight = 0; for (int i = 0; i < weights.length; ++i) { if (weights[i].id == doc.actor.id) return weights[i].weight; } return weight;"
                                },
                                "order": "asc"
                            }
                        },
                        "_source": {
                            "includes": ["published", "actor", "object", "target", "extra"]
                        },
                        "size": 100
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "sort": [
        {
            "published": {
                "order": "desc"
            }
        }
    ],
}
```

For clarity the painless function is as follow:

```
def weights = [{'id': 'mark', 'weight': 1}, {'id': 'jane', 'weight': 3}]; 
def weight = 0; 
for (int i = 0; i < weights.length; ++i) 
{ 
    if (weights[i].id == doc.actor.id) 
    return weights[i].weight; 
} 
return weight;
```

Elastic give me a compile error near the definition of the array. My guess is that I cannot define a list/array of JSON objects:

```
compile error","script_stack":["def weights = [{'id': 'mark', 'weight ...","               ^---- HERE"]....
```

Is there any way to accomplish this with or without a sorting script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Painless is not a javascript-like language. You can't just define an Array with a JSON-like syntax.

You can have the full documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/6.1/types.html#array-type) for array.
Also you have a create Map to represent your JSON objects.

But in your case you should definitively use [scripts params](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/modules-scripting-using.html#prefer-params)

Could you try something like :

```
"sort": {
    "_script": {
        "type": "number",
        "script": {
            "lang": "painless",
            "source": "def weight = 0; for (int i = 0; i < params.weights.length; ++i) { if (params.weights[i].id == doc['actor.id'].value) return params.weights[i].weight; } return weight;"
            "params": {
              "weights" :[{'id': 'mark', 'weight': 1}, {'id': 'jane', 'weight': 3}]
            } 
        },
        "order": "asc"
    }
}
```

By using params, you can defined your entry data with a JSON syntax AND furthemore you allow elasticsearch to cache the compiled version of your script, since the source will remain the same even if the weights array changes.

Comment: Excellent! Just tweaked the comparison inside the for with "if (params.weights[i].id == doc['actor.id'].value)" and works well. Thanks a lot